# svg.js: how to move and rotate togther?

Tags: animation, svg.js

I want to make the rect move and rotate togther, but the result is not as expected, so how to realize my requirement ?

```js
var ele = document.getElementById('svg_1')
var btn = document.getElementById('testBtn');
var timeline = new SVG.Timeline();
var x = 200,y = 0;
// btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const svgRect = SVG(ele);
  svgRect.timeline(timeline);
  svgRect.animate(5000, 0, 'now').dmove(x, y).loop();
  svgRect.animate(1500, 0, 'now').rotate(360).loop();
// })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@svgdotjs/svg.js@3.0.10/dist/svg.min.js"></script>
<svg width="800" height="600" style="border:1px solid lightblue;">
  <rect width="50" x="100" y="50" height="50" fill="#ffff00" stroke="#000000" id="svg_1"></rect>
</svg>
```

this is my demo url:  [codepen.io/echolove38/pen/jOxoQpK](https://codepen.io/echolove38/pen/jOxoQpK)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `rotate()` method in SVG.JS, it applies a transformation matrix to rotate the element around its center. It appears as though, when using the `animate()` method, it keeps the original center, even when you move the element, causing it to "orbit" around its initial position.

The quickest solution is to change from using `move(x, y)` to using `translate(x, y)`, which allows the rotation translation to use the initial center and allows you to override the `x` and `y` position of the translation matrix.

Modifying the example you linked to, it would look like this:

```
ele = document.getElementById('svg_1');

// Important note: when translating, you are specifying an _offset_ not a coordinate
// Moves 200 to the right from current position
const x = 200;

// Moves 50 up from current position
const y = -50;

const timeline = new SVG.Timeline();

const svgRect = SVG(ele);
svgRect.timeline(timeline);

svgRect.animate(1000, 0, 'now').translate(x, y).loop();
svgRect.animate(1500, 0, 'now').rotate(360).loop();
```